# How to adjust event.pageY to my new modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js, modal-dialog

I made a modal dialog using jquery-ui,it has absolute position.
In my new dialog,I want to obtain the mouse position using `event.pageY`.

However,`event.pageY` returns the position of my background page,and when I want to render a tooltip using

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
    return tooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px").style("left", d3.event.pageY + "px");
})
```

I didn't get the right position,instead,my tooltip seems like at the bottom of my dialog.

The tooltip has an absolute position too.

Please help me and show me how to adjust `event.PageY` to a right position in my dialog.

Comment: What is d3? Maybe post more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `event.pageY` return the absolute position of the background.
If I want to get the relative position in my dialog,I should minus the top of my dialog.
Since my dialog has an absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `d` as the event and accessing `d3.event` instead. There isn't enough code given to determine what that d3 is. In any case:

```
.on("mousemove", function(event) {
    return tooltip.style("top", event.pageY + "px").style("left", event.pageY + "px");
})
```

EDIT: In fact it's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: 'd3.event.pageY' == `event.pageY` in my case.D3 is a library of js